# wvdial t-mobile invaild dial command

Tags: raspberry-pi, 3g

I have an issue setting up wvdial on my raspberry.
I have used the same config for connecting to eplus via aldi sim card.

Always when I try to connect I get the error invaild dial command.
umtskeeper with sakis3g wasn't working that good for me.

Any ideas what I need to change? I've tried a lot of possibilities so far..

```
[Dialer pin]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB 1
Init1 = AT+CPIN="1622"

[Dialer umts]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
Modem Type = USB Modem
Ask Password = off
Stupid Mode = on
Carrier Check = on
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = ATS0=0
Init4 = AT+COPS?
Init5 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.t-d1.de"
Dial Command = AT
Phone = *99#
ISDN = off
Username = ''
Password = ''
Dial Attempts = 3
Auto Reconnect = on
```

the error message says

```
sudo wvdial umts
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: ATS0=0
ATS0=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+COPS?
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"T-Mobile D",2
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.t-d1.de"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.t-d1.de"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: AT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
AT*99***1#
ERROR
--> Invalid dial command.
--> Disconnecting at Sat Nov 28 18:35:01 2015
```

I have already deactivated the pin and added the usb modem to usb-modeswitch config file.. so... I ran out of ideas.